# Using table adapters to insert a new row doesn't do anything

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build my application and SQL Server 2005 to store the data. I created a table adapter, dataset and binded the controls to my already made form. The thing is, I'm trying to insert a new record into the database and it won't work!

I can fill the form with a record from the database and update it so I know its definitely connected correctly.  Every time I try to insert a new record, whether it's through a table adapter or manually, I just can't seem to get it to automatically save to the database.

I've put this under the save button

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click

    Dim CustomerRow As accountingdbDataSet.CustomerRow
    CustomerRow = Me.AccountingdbDataSet._Customer.NewCustomerRow()
    CustomerRow.customerID = CustomerIDBox.Text
    CustomerRow.customerName = FirstNameBox.Text
    CustomerRow.customerSurname = SurnameBox.Text
    CustomerRow.customerAddress1 = AddressBox1.Text
    CustomerRow.customerAddress2 = AddressBox2.Text
    CustomerRow.customerAddress3 = AddressBox3.Text
    CustomerRow.customerPostcode = PostcodeBox.Text
    CustomerRow.customerTelArea = AreaBox.Text
    CustomerRow.customerTelNumber = NumberBox.Text
    CustomerRow.customerEmail = EmailAddressBox.Text

    ' Add the row to the Region table
    Me.AccountingdbDataSet._Customer.Rows.Add(CustomerRow)

    ' Save the new row to the database
    Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Update(Me.AccountingdbDataSet._Customer)


End Sub
```

but that doesn't work. It complains about a NullException even though the fields in my database aren't set to null (apart from the customerID because that's the primary key). I've also tried

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click

Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.CustomerBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Update(Me.AccountingdbDataSet)

        MessageBox.Show("Updates to the database have been successful.", "Successful Updates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Updates to the database have failed.", "Unsuccessful Updates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try

End Sub
```

which only allows me to update a current record - not insert a new one. I do however have this inserted in the load page

```
Private Sub NewCustomerPage_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try

        Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AccountingdbDataSet.Customer)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The database file is unavailable", "Database Unavailable", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Me.Close()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Flush()
```

Comment: what does flush do? i tried it and its saying that it's not a part of the CustomerTableAdapter..